# viewBox attribute with svg height and width attributes set

Tags: d3.js, svg

If you look at [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mozipon/edit?js,output) svg image which has width and height attributes and a viewBox attribute set:

```
var width = width + margin.left + margin.right;
var height = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Then the svg does not scale at all.

But if I then comment out the width and height attributes then it does appear to scale like in [this bin](http://jsbin.com/xujoyo/edit?js,output).

I am very confused by the viewBox attribute, I see lots of examples online with a width, height and viewBox attribute all set.  I see the viewBox attribute as negated when there is a width and height attribute.

I am also puzzled by the width and height properties of the viewBox actually correspond to the actual space.

The docs say that you are specifying your own coordinate system but I don't understand what this means and how the width and height correspond to the actual width and height of the document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [svg viewBox attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335926/svg-viewbox-attribute)

Answer (score 5):

*`tl;dr:` `viewBox` is for drawing whats inside the SVG, `width` and `height` tell at what size to display it.*

The viewBox defines the canvas and coordinate system you are drawing your SVG into. If it says `viewBox="10 50 100 100"`, and you want to draw a square that covers the upper left quarter of your image, you'll write:

```
<svg viewBox="10 50 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="10" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
</svg>
```

Then, when you want to display your SVG, for example embeded into a html page, width and height tell at what size to display them, just like you would for an image tag:

```
<div>
  <svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="10 50 100 100"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="10" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

If your SVG was saved as an external file `drawing.svg`, you could express the same effect as

```
<div>
  <img src="drawing.svg" width="250" height="250" />
</div>
```

In both cases, the square you have drawn would cover the upper left quarter of the image, but since the SVG is drawn at an overall size of 250px ✕ 250px, the square has a side length of 125px ✕ 125px.

In other words, if the width defined in the viewBox is `a`, and the width defined on the element is `b`, the effect is the same as scaling everything inside the SVG (horizontally) with a factor of `b / a`.

(That obviously opens up the question what happens when viewBox height is `c`, element height is `d`, and the ratios `d / c ≠ b / a` don't match? That is what the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute describes.)

Formally, every combination of `width`, `height`, `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` can be written equivalently as a `transform` attribute. The algorithm for this is described [here](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform). (Note that for the `<svg>` element as used here in the example, the `x` and `y` attributes must always be 0.)