# Using rem with d3 (for purposes of keeping font sizes similar at different scales)

Tags: css, d3.js

Currently using d3 for the first time & mid tier knowledge of CSS.

Here is the [code pen](https://codepen.io/KarterF/pen/oNqoRER) I will reference in this questions - and also as a stack snippet:

```js
const padding = 30
const fakeData = [
  [0, 0],
  [100, 300],
  [300, 250],
  [500, 450]
]

function applyGraph(svg) {
  // Setup the axes
  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0 + padding, 200 - padding])
    .domain([500, 0])
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0 + padding, 200 - padding])
    .domain([0, 500])
  
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(4)
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4)
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis-rem')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${200 - padding})`)
    .call(xAxis)
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis-rem')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${padding}, 0)`)
    .call(yAxis)
  
  // Plot some data
  const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(d[0]))
    .y(d => yScale(d[1]))
  
  svg.append('path')
    .data([fakeData])
    .attr('class', 'line-rem')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('d', line)
}

var g1 = d3.select("#graph1")
var g2 = d3.select("#graph2")
applyGraph(g1)
applyGraph(g2)
```

```css
.line-rem {
   stroke-width: 0.4rem;
}

.axis-rem {
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg 
     id="graph1"
     viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     width="400" 
     height="400"/>
<svg 
     id="graph2"
     viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     width="200" 
     height="200"/>
```

I have a function (component) which renders a d3 graph based on some data. This function is reused in a number of places at different sizes / scales. My aim is to get the text and stroke width the same size regardless of the size the SVG is scaled to.

My initial thought was to use `rem` units as I have heard about them previously. My understanding is that this should make the size relative to the "root element". However even after using these units for `stroke-width` and `font-size` in the SVG, the text and the line appear to have different sizes.

Two questions:

1. Why does this happen? Is it because the "root element" is reset to be the `<svg>` tag or something similar?
2. How would I achieve this goal of making `stroke-width` and `font-size` (I would prefer not to hard code some `px` value in)?

Comment: Your axis dimensions are fixed in `applyGraph` but your vary your svg dimensions (despite a constant `viewBox` size)... what are open to changing ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Thanks for the response! Very new to d3 and `viewBox`. I was assuming that the `scaleLinear().range(...)` was refering to the view box's dimensions.

Do I have to change the `viewBox` to match the `height` and `width` on the `svg` component? 

I would be willing to have a variable sized `viewBox` (although not sure how that works at the moment) as eventually I want the graph to fill any horizontal space given.

Answer (score 0):

There are useful answers regarding use of `width` and `height` and `viewbox` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322617/viewbox-attribute-with-svg-height-and-width-attributes-set) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335926/how-to-use-the-svg-viewbox-attribute).

Your bigger chart is 'zoomed in' because the same 200x200 coordinate system is stretched over a larger SVG (400x400 vs 200x200).

If you dispense with the `viewBox` and change `applyGraph` to recognise the `width` and `height` of the `svg` then your charts will show the same font and stroke width:

```js
const padding = 30
const fakeData = [
  [0, 0],
  [100, 300],
  [300, 250],
  [500, 450]
]

function applyGraph(svg) {
  // get dimensions of svg
  const svgWidth = +svg.attr("width");
  const svgHeight = +svg.attr("height");

  // Setup the axes
  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0 + padding, svgWidth - padding])
    .domain([500, 0])
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0 + padding, svgHeight - padding])
    .domain([0, 500])
  
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(4)
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4)
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis-rem')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${svgHeight - padding})`)
    .call(xAxis)
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis-rem')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${padding}, 0)`)
    .call(yAxis)
  
  // Plot some data
  const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(d[0]))
    .y(d => yScale(d[1]))
  
  svg.append('path')
    .data([fakeData])
    .attr('class', 'line-rem')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('d', line)
}

var g1 = d3.select("#graph1")
var g2 = d3.select("#graph2")
applyGraph(g1)
applyGraph(g2)
```

```css
.line-rem {
   stroke-width: 0.4rem;
}

.axis-rem {
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg 
     id="graph1"
     width="400" 
     height="400"/>
<svg 
     id="graph2"
     width="200" 
     height="200"/>
```