# System Dark/Light mode favicon

Tags: html, image, svg

[solved]
I am trying to make a dark/light mode icon for my website, so I made the code:

```
<svg>
 <style>
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      .dark {
        display:none;
      }
      .light {
        display:true;
      }
    }
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
      .dark {
        display:true;
      }
      .light {
        display:none;
      }
    }
  </style>
<img x="0" y="0" class="dark" src="https://7c-code.tk/favicon/icon-dark.png" width="100px" height="100px" ></img>
<img x="0" y="0" class="light" src="https://7c-code.tk/favicon/icon-dark.png" width="100px" height="100px" ></img>
</svg>
```

It works correctly, but it can only render in html, so I changed it into

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <style>
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      .dark {
        display:none;
      }
      .light {
        display:true;
      }
    }
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
      .dark {
        display:true;
      }
      .light {
        display:none;
      }
    }
  </style>
<img x="0" y="0" class="dark" src="https://7c-code.tk/favicon/icon-dark.png" width="100px" height="100px" ></img>
<img x="0" y="0" class="light" src="https://7c-code.tk/favicon/icon-dark.png" width="100px" height="100px" ></img>
</svg>
```

Now all the elements are positioned to the bottom right for some reason, even though I specified an x and y position for the images. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Turns out I was just being dumb, I did not know that html img was different from svg image. Solved it, here is my code now:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <style>
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      .dark {
        display:none;
      }
      .light {
        display:true;
      }
    }
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
      .dark {
        display:true;
      }
      .light {
        display:none;
      }
    }
  </style>
<image x="0" y="0" class="dark" href="https://7c-code.tk/favicon/icon-dark.png" width="100px" height="100px" ></image>
<image x="0" y="0" class="light" href="https://7c-code.tk/favicon/icon-dark.png" width="100px" height="100px" ></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: SVG and HTML are two related but different Markup languages. IMG is an HTML tag, not an SVG tag. They will be displayed outside the SVG tag. The SVG tag for images is <IMAGE> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but you might be dealing with viewbox issues. If I'm not mistaken,  the `x=` and `y=` (viewbox attributes) must go on the SVG tag not on the `<image>` tag within the SVG.

Also, you may have misspelled the [SVG `<image>` tag](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/svg-image-tag/)

See this other answer for details re the viewbox:

[How to use the <svg> viewBox attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335926/how-to-use-the-svg-viewbox-attribute/65118033#65118033)

Comment: Turns out I was really dumb. I did mess up on the image tags, I didn't know it was different from html. Thanks!